# HTTP Method For Performing Subroutine on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, http

This might seem like an odd question and is probably very specific to our current requirements but I couldn't find anything through Google, so I thought I would give this a shot.

I am working in ASP.NET C# MVC4, and with a backend that is a legacy database system.  We have two MVC projects; one for the API which interacts with the database and one for the front end which returns Views etc and interacts with the API.  From the API, we are able to run subroutines that exist on the backend database server.

I am making an HTTP request from the front end to the API which contains JSON-encoded data.  The API will use this to run a subroutine on the backend (the subroutine will save the data on the server and send out emails).

My question is this: What HTTP method should I use in this case?

For right now, I chose a POST request, and since this isn't an idempotent action, I think it is the best choice but it isn't really a CREATE operation, so I wanted to ask if anyone had any different advice.

Comment: how about `PUT` then?

Comment: If I understand you right, you are actually creating a new job of subroutine on your server, so it's ineed a `POST`. `PUT` will mean it's an update action (altough it's getting mixed up with POST, it's all about the convention you pick).

Comment: @m_wilczynsk, hmmm "creating a new job of subroutine" is a good way of looking at it.  I think I will stick with POST for now.  Thanks a lot.  I'm still new to this, so before I made a decision, I thought I would check if I was making a big, obvious mistake. :P

Comment: Remember that it's all about convention. I've seen people using `POST` for update and `PUT` for create. Just stick with one convention and don't mix them up.